# Php How to put a variable with in a variable

Tags: php, variables

I have this code:

```
echo $b1[1][wood];   // It would say 100
```

But i want to change the 1  in $b1, for example:

```
$id = 1;
echo $b(The $id here)[1][wood];
```

I tried

```
echo $b'.$id.'[1][wood];
```

But it didnt work. Does any one have any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: *Ick*. Try to avoid ["variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) - not many languages have such a construct, but work fine anyway. Don't confuse "convenient" (per the documentation's wording) with "appropriate".

Comment: Milan's answer below is perfect for this. however, I suggest you would want to try out using array instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$id = 1;
echo ${'b'.$id}[1]['wood'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$varName = 'b' . $id;
echo ${$varName}[1]['wood'];
```

(Notice I also put quotes around 'wood' - PHP treats `wood` as an undefined constant, which will work, but generates a warning)

A better solution would be to avoid variable variables altogether. Couldn't you just make $id another dimension of the array? `$b[$id][1]['wood']` ?

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use an array() type ?